# How do I calculate the impedance of elements in a circuit given only equivalent impedance and angular frequency?

Tags: ac, impedance

See photo included below. I've tried working this problem for an hour using phasors, voltage/current dividers, and Ohm's law, but I can't figure it out. It's given that equivalent impedance Z_eq = 2-j2 kOhms and that frequency is 4000 rad/s, but I don't see how to find the individual impedance a of the elements in the diagram. Any ideas? [image: circuit schematic]

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I'm an idiot. Impedance of a resistor is real while impedance of a capacitor is purely imaginary and depends on angular frequency. Thus, the impedance of each element can be determined by inspection of the equivalent impedance.